# Block element text overflow problem in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm making a "sort elements" web game using jQuery, HTML & CSS. While everything works fine in FF, IE8, Opera, Chrome, I'm having problem with IE7 wrapping words inside block elements.

Here's how it looks in IE7 (*wrong*):
[Link (*cannot post images as a new user*)](http://i50.tinypic.com/2lt0jdi.jpg)

In IE8 the box with wrapped text would just expand to fit it whole in one line without any overflows. *Sorry, can't give another link as a new user*

*Don't mind the element order as it's random. Elements are dynamically generated by jQuery.*

HTML code:

```
<div class="ui-sortable" id="area">
  <span class="object">: </span>
  <span class="object">1998- </span>
  <span class="object">ISSN 1392-4087</span>
  <span class="object">, </span>
  <span class="object">. </span>
  <span class="object">nepriklausomas savaitraštis buhalteriams, finansininkams, auditoriams</span>
  <span class="object">. </span>
  <span class="object">. </span>
  <span class="object">. </span>
  <span class="object">Vilnius</span>
  <span class="object">1998- </span>
  <span class="object"><em>Apskaitos, audito ir mokesčių aktualijos</em></span>
</div>
```

CSS code (irrelevant info like fonts & colors removed):

```
#area {
  min-height: 160px;
  width: 760px;
}
.object {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}
```

Any comments on why does IE7 does that? How do I make these spans expand to fit the whole text in one line in IE7 and not wrap the text or make overflows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it out myself in IE7, and when you just add 'white-space: nowrap' to the span.object, it should solve the problem. Floating the block elements works just fine, so don't change that.

See image for the test result: http://xs.to/image-B3F6_4BDE909D.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem. Floats and automatic widths just don't mix. You'll also have issues when it comes to something being wider than the width.

Why not leave it inline? If you need a box, add padding:

```
span.object { padding: 6px; }
```

**Edit:** if you don't want them to break across lines add:

```
span.object { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Far easier than getting floats to do this particular task.

Comment: Doesn't really work with multiple lines. Changed to inline and removed floats. Result: the .objects are now breaking in to multiple lines which defies the idea of them looking as single elements. And there's terrible overflows on random longer elements and the ones near div edges.

Comment: @Adomas: add `white-space: nowrap` to avoid wrapping.

Comment: There have to be several lines of spans, but the text inside span has to fit in one line without breaking at any point. Nowrap rule makes all spans fit in one line overflowing the parent div. Mind you, every other modern browser has no problems with it, just IE7 (haven't tested IE6).